# Joining SSAS with external data in PowerBI

Tags: ssas, powerbi

We are trying to combine data from a SSAS Olap cube and an excel table using PowerBI.

No way to create the needed relations due to every data table having duplicate values.

As far as we are we ended up opening the SSAS Olap cube once for every dimension the excel table needs to link to and once more for the whole data on the cube.

As an example, if our excel table contains data related to customer and product, we need to:

1. add a SSAS data source selecting only the customer dimension
2. add a SSAS data source selecting only the product dimension
3. add a SSAS data source selecting all data
4. add an Excel data source
5. Create the needed links:

5.1 Customer-dimension (SSAS 1) to Excel customer

5.2 Product-dimension (SSAS 2) to Excel product

5.3 Customer-dimension (SSAS 1) to Customer-dimension (SSAS 3)

5.4 Product-dimension (SSAS 2) to Product-dimension (SSAS 3)

Obviously 5.3 and 5.4 seems totally redundant, and the whole definition quite more complex than expected.

Is there a better (simpler!) way to do it?

Comment: What's the reason for the Excel file? Any way to get the Excel's Customer and Product data into the respective DimCustomer, DimProduct?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about what's in the Excel file, and how you want to join it to the cube. Some questions I have: why does every data table have duplicate values? Are you not joining on the key fields? How did you come up with the 5 steps above? For example, step 3 - why bring in 2 dimensions individually, then the whole cube? I imagine you have a reason for each of the 5 steps. One thought I have that might simplify what you're trying to do is to not import the from SSAS directly, but rather import from the underlying data mart that SSAS is sourcing from.

Comment: @manderson, the excel file is where users have data not included in our SSAS system that they would like to join with the cube. It can come from lots of external source, they get some data that they would like to add to the standard defined analysis. We have no control on what they are getting, be it statistic data from somewhere, business data not relevant to others, etc. All we ask them is to have the proper identifying keys to lin with the "official" data in the cube.

Comment: @leonard, maybe we are doing something incorrectly, that's why we ask because it seems ilogical.

Comment: @leonard .. oops hit return too early :). Our cube has a fact table with say customer id and sales by month, a dimension with customer id and name. The excel file has customer id and age (or whatever you like). When trying to define the link between the cube and the excel table we get an error saying that the tables have duplicate values ... sure we are doing something wrong!

Comment: If there aren't duplicate Customer ID's in your dimension or in your Excel file, I'm not sure why you're getting that message. There must be something causing it, but without direct access to your cube, it's almost impossible to say what it is. Did you try importing the data from the underlying data mart, rather than from the cube? That might at least get you past this problem. Otherwise, if you do figure it out, be sure to post the answer back here. Sorry, I'm not more help.